# SQL database ERROR: function format(real, integer) does not exist

Tags: sql, function, format, decimal

```
SELECT 
    p.product_name,
    FORMAT(p.unit_price, 2) AS current_unit_price,
    FORMAT(p.previous_unit_price, 2) AS previous_unit_price,
    FORMAT(((p.unit_price - p.previous_unit_price) / p.previous_unit_price * 100), 0) AS percentage_increase
FROM 
    products p
WHERE 
    ((p.unit_price - p.previous_unit_price) / p.previous_unit_price * 100) NOT BETWEEN 40 AND 50
ORDER BY 
    percentage_increase ASC;
```

From the code I've written above, I'm trying to convert the number to be formatted using only 2 decimals yet I get this error:

> function format(real, integer) does not exist
>
> HINT: no function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

I tried looking up online, some said to use FORMAT or ROUND and I've tried those but get the same error. What am I doing wrong? To my knowledge, FORMAT is a valid function.

Comment: Which **RDBMS** is this for? This is not "standard" SQL ....

Comment: @marc_s I'm not too sure, we just started this course and I'm not too familiar with it. Sorry that this is unclear

Comment: Looks like it's supposed to be MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format but you are using it in Postgres judging by the error. You need to get clear which DBMS you are using, and which one you are *supposed* to be using, as they are all different. Side notes, because if you are just starting out you will want some tips: Don't use formatting functions, as that should really be done at the application/presentation level on the client, not in a bare SQL query.

Comment: `BETWEEN` is often a bad idea, because it includes (or excludes in the case of `NOT BETWEEN`) *both* ends of the range, which is often not desired.

Comment: What does `select version();`, `select @@version;` or `select * from V$VERSION;` return?``